# Why configure bridge in hostapd.conf

Tags: linux, wifi, hostapd

In a lot of hostapd documentation (is there a single comprehensive one that covers all options?) I read that it is necessary to configure the bridge to which the wireless interface belongs to, using the hostapd `bridge` directive instead of adding them the way you would usually configure an interface as part of a bridge. Why is this required? Is it possible to configure multiple wireless networks on different bridge that way?

Comment: I recently had a problem where the `bridge` directive was preventing the AP from working; removing the `bridge` fixed the problem, so I'm not sure it *is* required, or maybe it just sin't required any longer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can't add the WiFi device to the bridge until it is up and running in AP mode.  So you can specify a bridge here, and hostapd will add it to the bridge once it becomes possible.

It's only needed if you want to bridge LAN and WiFi traffic, so the LAN and wireless clients become one big network on the same IP subnet.  If you are configuring your machine as a router (e.g. with iptables, and the wireless clients are in a different IP subnet to the wired clients) then you don't need the bridge device.

Most commercial WiFi routers bridge the traffic between the WiFi and wired interfaces so using the bridge will replicate this behaviour and is much simpler to set up.